# How do I calculate in Matlab the 95% confidence interval with lsqcurvefit?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, goodness-of-fit

due to some problems in Matlab with fixed parameters, I had to switch from the std. `fit` command to `lsqcurvefit`.

For the normal  `fit` command, one of the output parameters is `gof`, from which I can calculate the +/- of each parameter and the r^2 value.

That should be possible for the `lsqcurvefit` as well. But I don't get it as one of the output parameters.

Or to put my question in other words: how do I calculate the +/- of a fitparamter from the `lsqcurvefit`?
Can someone help me with that?

Thanks, Niko

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "+/- of each parameter"? +/- 1 standard error? Do you need exactly the same statistics between the two methods (note that the two functions can use very different fitting approaches).

Comment: Which part of the `gof` output did you use, and how did you use it to compute your error?

Comment: Maybe he refers to the output of the `predint` function.

Comment: So, what I used so far was the following:` level = 2*tcdf(-1,gof3.dfe);
 ConfBoundaries = confint(Fitresult,level);` where I calculated the 95% confidence interval, but as horchler wrote above, +/- one std error would also be fine.

Comment: If you want a 95% CI, you just have to use the function like `ci = confint(fitresult,0.95)`. Niko, where did you get this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Get all the output parameters of `lsqcurvefit` and use them in `nlparci` like so:

```
[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,lambda,jacobian] =...
                               lsqcurvefit(@myfun,x0,xdata,ydata);
conf = nlparci(x,residual,'jacobian',jacobian)
```

Now `conf` contains an `N x 2` matrix for your `N` fit parameters. Each row of `conf` gives the upper and lower 95% confidence interval for the corresponding parameter.

Comment: According to the documentation, `parci` is supposed to be used with the output of `nlinfit`. How do you know one can use it with the output of `lsqcurvefit`, too? In fact, the documentation of `lsqcurvefit` explicitly states that for CIs one should use `nlinfit`.

Comment: `nlparci` takes the coefficient prediction, the residual, and the jacobian as arguments. One can obtain these just as well from `lsqcurvefit` as from `nlinfit`.